# Remove first <p> tag and replace the second <p> tag with <br />

Tags: php

I need to Remove first < p> tag and replace the second

tag with < /br>

For example :
I have a string '< p>Lorem Ipsum< /p>< p>is simply dummy< /p>'

I need the result as

Lorem Ipsum< br />is simply dummy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
$input = '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p><p>is simply dummy</p>';

$output = nl2br(trim(str_replace(array("<p>","</p>"),array("","\n"),$input)));
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/Kmhkh